# Нужна карусель как на Ulmart

Tags: веб-дизайн

Ищу варианты реализации мини-галереи как на старом ульмарте. У товаров.

Увы иначе объяснить не могу что хочу) Вроде бы и карусель или слайдер... переискал кучу всего... Нормальное название так и не выяснил...

Может кто уже делал?

Или знает легкий плагин реализующий это (jQuery)?

На всякий случай поясняю: интересует есть ли готовые решения, т.к. мне их найти не удалось.
Или же мне придется писать очередной велосипед?

**Обновление**

Я уже разбирал код страницы, особенно порадовал коммент "//Если перец прищел..." =) Боюсь что код слишком крив для использования. Я искал нечто аналогичное на jQuery.

Из того велосипеда который начал писать удалось впихнуть все картинки в div и скрыть переполнение див находится в контейнере, скроллы спрятаны. Когда то решал эту задачу, поэтому быстро удалось написать)

Осталось реализовать скролл, если картинок много через стрелки по краям или другим способом.

Так же надо сделать замену основного изображения при наведении мыши.

Вместо нового окна при нажатии навешан fancybox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решением оказался следующий код:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('/*класс миниатюр*/').mouseenter(function(){
        var source = $(this).attr('src');
        source = source.replace('/*папка с миниатюрами*/', '/*папка с большими изображениями*/');
        $("/*айди элемента содержащего большую картинку*/").attr("src", source);
    })
});
```

Код еще не в лучшем состоянии, как закончу - обновлю и закрою вопрос.

Буду рад помощи в дописании.

Сейчас стоят несколько вопросов:

- как правильно организовать прокручивающийся контейнер с изображениями
- как организовать прокрутку контейнера если его длинна превышает определенное значение
- как найти элемент если классы и айди объявлены выше по дереву DOM чем картинки

Answer (score 1):

На сайте смотрите реализацию в main.js после комента "убойная цена"

найти можно так - грузим сайт в chrome, в дев консоли выбираем элемент меняющийся, в данном случае tr, **правой кнопкой -> break on -> subtree modifications**, нажимаем на стрелочку  и смотрим где вызов произошёл.

**Обновление**

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/LZ7Eq/ примените там scrollto плагин например.

Comment: Я уже разбирал код страницы, особенно порадовал коммент "//Если перец прищел..." =) Боюсь что код слишком крив для использования. Я искал нечто аналогичное на jQuery.

Из того велосипеда который начал писать удалось впихнуть все картинки в div и скрыть переполнение див находится в контейнере, скроллы спрятаны. Когда то решал эту задачу, поэтому быстро удалось написать)

Осталось реализовать скролл, если картинок много через стрелки по краям или другим способом.

Так же надо сделать замену основного изображения при наведении мыши.

Вместо нового окна при нажатии навешан fancybox.